# How to put multi-subfigure on a single page with different main caption?

Tags: graphics, captions, subfloats

I have to add 8 figures on one page using subfigure command in such a way that first 4 figures should be placed with one caption and next 4 figures with other caption. Please guide me with sample of a code, how shall i do?? The example is shown in below attached figure:
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX. SX. Have you already tried a bit? Can you show us the code you have so far? This shows everyone that you're putting effort into this yourself, which generally increases your chances of finding help

Comment: Well, why not use two figure environments with 4 subfigures each?

Comment: Actually, you can put multiple figure \captions in a single figure (not to be confused with subfigure captions).  Nor do you really need any of the many subfigure environments available.

Answer (score 1):

You can put two `minipage` environment, each with it's own `\caption` and four `\subcaptionbox` commands into one `figure`, if they should not float onto different pages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}% for example-image

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering
    \subcaptionbox{First}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{Second}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \subcaptionbox{Third}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \subcaptionbox{Forth}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \caption{This is the first figure}
  \end{minipage}

  \bigskip
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering
    \subcaptionbox{First}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{Second}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \subcaptionbox{Third}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \subcaptionbox{Forth}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \caption{This is the second figure}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if they should be allowed to float onto different pages, you can simply use two figures:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}% for example-image

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{First}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subcaptionbox{Second}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \subcaptionbox{Third}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
  \subcaptionbox{Forth}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}}
  \caption{This is the first figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{First}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subcaptionbox{Second}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \subcaptionbox{Third}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
  \subcaptionbox{Forth}{\includegraphics[height=5em,width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}}
  \caption{This is the second figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: two figures]

Answer (score 1):

you can have two captions in one float. with use of `subfig` packages the solution ca be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
    \subfloat[First]{\includegraphics[height=7em,width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[Second]{\includegraphics[height=7em,width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

    \subfloat[Third]{\includegraphics[height=7em,width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[Forth]{\includegraphics[height=7em,width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \caption{This is the first figure}

  \bigskip
    \subfloat[First]{\includegraphics[height=7em,width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[Second]{\includegraphics[height=7em,width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

    \subfloat[Third]{\includegraphics[height=7em,width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[Forth]{\includegraphics[height=7em,width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \caption{This is the second figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]